# Why is this applicative instance unlawful?

Tags: haskell, applicative

I was reading about monad transformers and found this apparently well known article - [A Gentle Introduction to Monad Transformers](https://two-wrongs.com/a-gentle-introduction-to-monad-transformers). What caught my attention was the part where the author describes an applicative instance for a makeshift `ExceptT` transformer, but leaves a warning mentioning that that instance is unlawful.

Here's the code:

```
data EitherIO e a = EitherIO {
    runEitherIO :: IO (Either e a)
}

instance Functor (EitherIO e) where
    fmap f = EitherIO . fmap (fmap f) . runEitherIO

instance Applicative (EitherIO e) where
    pure    = EitherIO . return . Right
    f <*> x = EitherIO $
        liftA2 (<*>)
            (runEitherIO f)
            (runEitherIO x)
```

And the warning:

> Warning: A very sharp-sighted reader has pointed out to me that this applicative instance is unlawful. Specifically, it executes the side effects of the right-hand side unconditionally. The expectation of a lawful instance is that it should only execute the side-effects of the right-hand side if the left-hand side was a successful operation.

I am assuming that specifically the implementation of `<*>` is the problem.

So my main question is: **which laws exactly does this instance not satisfy?**

From what I can see, the four applicative laws are satisfied (I might be wrong of course). The author says that the problem is that side effects on the right (I am assuming, to the right of `<*>`) are executed even if the left-hand side was not a successful operation (I am assuming, "successful operation" means that the IO action would yield a `Right` value when executed).

While I can see that it makes sense from a usage standpoint, it would still be enlightening to see which laws exactly are not satisfied here, and why.

Also, the explanation of why the instance is unlawful mentions side-effects, which makes the reasoning kind of apply only for the IO monad? But at the end of the text, as a finishing move, we change the IO monad to a general monad and make it a parameter of the described data type. This leads me to another question: if we imagine that I was writing this monad transformer myself, **what kind of reasoning would I need to apply, to notice that the described applicative instance is indeed unlawful, without resorting to thinking about specific monads that could be used with this transformer?**

Comment: `IO` is not the only monad for which it makes sense to talk about side-effects. For example, in the `State` the term "side-effect" means updating the state. In general a side-effect is anything that happens "behind the scenes", anything that isn't directly encoded in the monadic computation itself.

Comment: Have you tried proving the laws?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin thank you for your comment, it actually clarifies a very important point that I'm glad to see before I delve deeper into Haskell.

Comment: @augustss unfortunately I am not familiar with a way to formally prove these laws, but I definitely tried to analyze them and find some way one of them could not be satisfied by the given instance, but didn't find anything

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Applicative` instance is lawful.  In fact, it's the same instance as [`Compose`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.3.0.0/docs/Data-Functor-Compose.html) `IO (Either e)`.  Compositions of applicative functors are applicative (this is one of the very nice things that applicatives have that monads don't).

However, the following is also listed in the laws section of [the documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html):

> If `f` is also a `Monad`, it should satisfy
>
> ```
> pure = return
> (<*>) = ap
> (*>) = (>>)
> ```

And this is where the problem is, since there can be no monad that corresponds to the given applicative (this is where the comment about conditional execution of the RHS comes into play).  So the `Applicative` and `Monad` instances, while each in isolation is lawful, do not agree, and that is punishable by death.

Comment: In other words, a [non-]commutative `Monad` is supposed to be a [non-]commutative `Applicative`. (Personally, I think this requirement is needlessly strict, and we should somehow differentiate effects that we mean to be commutative or not, but that’s a separate issue.)